# Read only users - list all the buckets I have read rights to

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph, radosgw

We are using ceph and have several buckets.

We are using one read-only user to make backups of these buckets.

If I know the list, I can backup all my bucket.

I don't understand why, but I can't list all buckets.

Is it at all possible in ceph radosgw? I suspect not.

The policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::user/read-only"]},
    "Action": [
       "s3:ListBucket",
       "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
       "s3:GetObject"
     ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
    ]
  }]
}
```

And I don't have anything special at the user level.

But when I try to list, I get the following:

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xx
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export MC_HOST_ceph=https://${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}@radosgwdns
mc ls ceph
mc ls ceph/
mc ls ceph/bucket
```

Only the last command is listing things.

In this link it is said that it is basically not possible:
https://help.switch.ch/engines/documentation/s3-like-object-storage/s3_policy/

```
Only S3 bucket policy is available, S3 user policy is not implemented in Ceph S3.
```

On this release page, they maybe speak about it:
https://ceph.io/releases/v16-2-0-pacific-released/

```
RGW: Improved configuration of S3 tenanted users.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you get access to a bucket with a bucket policy to a user it will not appear in the user's bucket listing. If you want it to be you can create a subuser with `none` permission and again give access to it using bucket policy. Now when the subuser lists buckets it will see the bucket and because of `none` permission, it has only access to the bucket you specified.
The principal for the subuser would be like this:

```
"Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam:::user/MAIN_USER:SUBUSER"]},
```